# Find the number of ways of ordering a dozen out of $31$ cones

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

A Certain Ice-cream store has $31$ flavours of ice-creams available. In how many ways can we order a dozen ice-cream cones if

$a)$ we don't want the same flavor more than once?

$b)$ a flavor may be ordered as many as $12$ times?

$c)$ a flavor may be ordered not more than $11$ times?

I think if there are no restrictions then it will be C(12+31-1, 31) but I dont know how to solve this when there are restrictions like this question.Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) $\dfrac{31!}{(31-12)!12!}=141120525$

b) $\dfrac{(31+12-1)!}{(31-1)!12!}=11058116888$

c) first take alle possibble combinations, so 11058116888.0, then take all 31 combinations which do have more than 11 of the same flavor and subtract:
$11058116888-31=11058116857$